# How do I handle GRPC disconnects?

Tags: nestjs

In NestJS I have a GRPC client that sometimes disconnects. If a disconnect happens, NestJS doesn't run any code anymore and forces me to restart it.

How do I handle GRPC client disconnects? Is there a event listener for that?

I would like to these error events:

- `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses`
- `Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed`

Comment: Do you see any specific error messages or other output when the gRPC client disconnects?

Comment: Hey @murgatroid99,

two of these error events are:

- `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses`
- `Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding following lines prevents the Node process from crashing and gives the user the opportunity to handle the GRPC disconnects:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```